# How to protect WinForms app from direct-SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-injection

i have some WinForms app (Framework to develop some simple apps), written in C#. 
My framework later would be used to develop win forms applications. Other developers they are beginers often and sometimes do not use Parameters - they write direct SQL in code. So first i need somehow to do protection in my framework base classes in C#.
I have some basse class, which performs all the SQL action so i think i can put here some checking, before executing queries...
How i can get protection in C# against direct SQL..? Some example would be very usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your colleagues are writing out their SQL statements, there's no guaranteed/realistic way you can protect against SQL injection except to protect against it manually using parameters in all queries. Even providing a mechanism in your framework isn't a perfect solution since you can still get around it by simply ignoring it (or forgetting to use it).

Instead of rolling your own framework, consider using an ORM such as [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org), which takes care of this issue for you (and you don't have to write SQL statements yourself most of the time).